# How to truncate tables generated by persisted streams in WSO2 DAS

Tags: wso2-das

Is there any way to truncate the tables created by persisting the event streams in WSO2 Data Analytics Server (WSO2 DAS)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can either purge old data using Management Console per stream or purge all the data in a table globally.

Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS301/Purging+Data

Comment: It's a scheduling right then it will take some time to start the purge. Is there any way to immediately truncate the tables even in the backend.

Comment: You can use "deleteTables" command with the shell script <PRODUCT_HOME>/bin/analytics-backup.sh as in https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=48288726